# what's the difference between `type FooFn <Bar> = (bar: Bar) => any` and `type FooFn = <Bar> (bar: Bar) => any`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Just like in the Q's topic;

what's the difference between `type FooFn <Bar> = (bar: Bar) => any` and `type FooFn = <Bar> (bar: Bar) => any`.

Obviously, 1st snipped requires the use of type arguments, while 2nd doesn't. But that's the 1st time I've encountered this syntax, and I know nothing about it.

I want to know;

- Does it have any name I can use to google it and read more on the subject?
- When `type FooFn = <Bar> ...` should be used over `type FooFn <Bar> = ...`?
- How can I be certain it will evaluate to the correct type?

Technical stuff like that.

Comment: `type F<T> = ...` is a generic *type*, while `type G = <T>(...)` is a generic *function*. The linked q/a has more detailed information.